# How to add a script at the beginning of the <head> tag before all other scripts in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets, hook-wordpress, cookieyes

I've been looking for a few days in the stack overflow here but I can't find the answer to my problem. I'm trying to add the Cookie Yes script, to insert the cookie banner on my WordPress site. The script must be loaded at the beginning of the  tag before any other script, because it must preventively block the other Facebook, analytics, etc. scripts.
I tried adding this to my child-theme's function.php file:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'cookieyes_script', 0 );
 
function cookieyes_script() {
    echo '<!-- Start cookieyes banner --><script id="cookieyes" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn-cookieyes.com/client_data/557849044ec07b9e401db693/script.js"></script><!-- End cookieyes banner --> ';
}
```

But the plugins that add the other scripts are always inserted before the one I want to add. Thank you very much.

Here the real example:

in function.php file

```
/* add script at the top of head tag */
add_action('wp_head', 'add_top_head_script',0);

function cookieyes_script() {
    echo '<!-- Start cookieyes banner --> <script id="cookieyes" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn-cookieyes.com/client_data/754d136f697eda5270dfe657/script.js"></script> <!-- End cookieyes banner -->';
}
```

[page source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uioHn.jpg)

Comment: What you've pasted here is a `function` that isn't called. Can you share how this information is being output to the DOM? Are you hooking an event? Where is this function being called, exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I took the action for granted. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

One way you might be able to get this done is with the `wp_head` action with `0` as the priority...

```
function cookieyes_script() {
    echo '<!-- Start cookieyes banner --><script id="cookieyes" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn-cookieyes.com/client_data/557849044ec07b9e401db693/script.js"></script><!-- End cookieyes banner --> ';
}
add_action("wp_head", "cookieyes_script", 0);
```

One issue here is that if another script uses this same priority of `0` the hook that is registered first will be higher.  That said the default priority for `add_action` is `10` so probably safe here.

Comment: Yes I tried to give priority 0 (someone here on Stack Overflow also suggests negative numbers -100) but unfortunately, the other scripts are still inserted first.

Comment: Can you share more about how those other scripts are being added? Could me and others here better troubleshoot.

Comment: Ok added the real example

Comment: Ok added the real example. It's the only thing I am able to share. I think that all the scripts that comes before the cookie script are injected with gtag manager. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the google tag manager account.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add scripts on top of wp_head you can use the priority variable in add_action. 0 is supposed to be the highest priority, but if something already has a 0 priority, you can use a negative one. Here is an example in your case:

```
/* add script at the top of head tag */
function cookieyes_script() {
    echo '<!-- Start cookieyes banner --> <script id="cookieyes" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn-cookieyes.com/client_data/754d136f697eda5270dfe657/script.js"></script> <!-- End cookieyes banner -->';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'add_top_head_script', -100);
```

Source: [How to add a script on top of wp_head in Wordpress](https://wpgum.com/tips-tricks/how-to-add-a-script-on-top-of-head-in-wordpress/)